# How do I control the size of this shell without it being overridden?

Tags: java, shell, swt

I need some SWT help.

I built this shell with multiple get text labels.  The labels are controlling the size of the shell, but I want the shell to be 250x200 pixels.  I have the size set before I open the shell.  How do I keep it from being overridden?  I want to eventually be able to put in 1000 rows and be able to scroll down, instead of having a giant window I cannot do I anything with.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;

public class JavaLabelTable {

private Label status;
private Display display;
private Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.CENTER | SWT.V_SCROLL);

public JavaLabelTable(Display display)
{
    initUT(display);
}

public void initUT(Display display)
{
    int q = 110;
    int w = 40;
    int e = q - w;
    int i;
    int y = 120;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
    Label RegisterLabels[] = new Label[y];
    status = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER); 
    GridData gd2 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);   
    status.setLayoutData(gd2);
    gd2.widthHint = q;
    gd2.heightHint = 15;
    gd2.horizontalSpan = 3;

    for(i=1; i<y; i++)
    {
        if(i % 3 == 1)
        {
            GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
            RegisterLabels[i] = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
            RegisterLabels[i].setLayoutData(gd1);
            RegisterLabels[i].setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
            gd1.widthHint = w;
            gd1.horizontalSpan = 1;
            RegisterLabels[i].setText(Integer.toString(b));
            b++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i % 3 == 2)
            {
                GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
                RegisterLabels[c] = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                RegisterLabels[c].setLayoutData(gd1);
                RegisterLabels[c].setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
                Color col1 = new Color(display, 255, 255, 255);
                RegisterLabels[c].setBackground(col1);
                gd1.widthHint = e;
                gd1.horizontalSpan = 1;
                RegisterLabels[c].getText();
                c++;
            }
            else
            {
                GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
                RegisterLabels[i] = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
                RegisterLabels[i].setLayoutData(gd1);
                RegisterLabels[i].setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
                gd1.widthHint = 20;
                gd1.horizontalSpan = 1;

            }
        }
    }

    shell.setSize(250, 200);
    status.getText();    
    shell.setText("Running");
    shell.pack();
    centerWindow(shell);
    shell.open();   


while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
{
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    {
        display.sleep();
    }}
}

private void centerWindow(Shell shell) 
{

    Rectangle bds = shell.getDisplay().getBounds();

    Point p = shell.getSize();

    int nLeft = (bds.width - p.x) / 2;
    int nTop = (bds.height - p.y) / 2;

    shell.setBounds(nLeft, nTop, p.x, p.y);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    JavaLabelTable ex = new JavaLabelTable(display);
    display.dispose();
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `shell.pack()` - this sets the size of the Shell to the 'preferred' size determined from the size of its contents.

`pack()` is equivalent to:

```
setSize(computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did take that out, but the window ends up shrinking the content inside the shell.  I have specified label sizes, but making the window smaller resizes everything inside of it.  How to do I lock the size of the contents within the shell?

Comment: The point of using things like GridLayout is to resize controls when you resize the shell. In any case you should probably be using a `Table` here rather than trying to recreate it with Labels.

Comment: I tried that before.  I had trouble getting an asyncexec to work with it. So I went this route. But I could try it again.  at least the table automatically creates a scroll bar.